# Path to Application Support on Mac in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm attempting to read a file on the path on Mac `~/Library/Application Support/file_name.cert` but cannot reach it using the `fs.readFileSync` Node.js module.

How do I read this file?

Comment: Could you be more specific on the context of your application and the way you try to read the file ?

Answer (score 3):

From what you wrote I am guessing the '~' character is the culprit. Your shell normally replaces this with your home directory, but this is not the case with Node.js (or any other program). So you'll have to replace it with your home directory like so:

```js
// Incorrect path due to ~
//const filename = '~/Library/Application Support/file_name.cert';

// Correct path
const filename = process.env.HOME + '/Library/Application Support/file_name.cert';

// Now read will succeed
const data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
```